# why bgl meshes flip when nothing is selected?

Tags: python, scripting, opengl, gpu-module, bgl

As described in [API](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/gpu.html) the following script will create a mesh from *active object* using *bgl* module:

```
import bpy
import gpu
import bgl
import numpy as np
from random import random
from gpu_extras.batch import batch_for_shader

mesh = bpy.context.active_object.data
mesh.calc_loop_triangles()

vertices = np.empty((len(mesh.vertices), 3), 'f')
indices = np.empty((len(mesh.loop_triangles), 3), 'i')

mesh.vertices.foreach_get(
    "co", np.reshape(vertices, len(mesh.vertices) * 3))
mesh.loop_triangles.foreach_get(
    "vertices", np.reshape(indices, len(mesh.loop_triangles) * 3))

vertex_colors = [(random(), random(), random(), 1) for _ in range(len(mesh.vertices))]

shader = gpu.shader.from_builtin('3D_SMOOTH_COLOR')
batch = batch_for_shader(
    shader, 'TRIS',
    {"pos": vertices, "color": vertex_colors},
    indices=indices,
)

def draw():
    bgl.glEnable(bgl.GL_DEPTH_TEST)
    batch.draw(shader)
    bgl.glDisable(bgl.GL_DEPTH_TEST)

bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add(draw, (), 'WINDOW', 'POST_VIEW')
```

But the created mesh flips when nothing is selected:

[image]

Please help!

Comment: Script draws a randomly vertex  coloured bgl representation of mesh. based on the context active object when run. It keeps drawing this same object.  Running with no object selected will cause an error.  To draw dynamically based on context object will need to adjust shader data based on this, and pass (for example) context as an argument to the draw call back method. (See other examples)

Comment: @batFinger I already know what the script does. my question is about when the mesh is created (so no errors would happen). after the mesh(es) is(are) created if we deselect everything, any bgl mesh would be flipped. I'm searching for a GL option or something like that to solve the problem

Comment: @batFinger I've tested adding flipping indices. It doesn't work either!

Comment: To clarify this. For me if run on default cube, no issue when selecting another object.   Is this the case for you. If so it leads towards the concavities in mesh above, and if this effects the bgl display on screen  when active.

Comment: @batFinger thanks for reply. It happens for everything. If you look precisely at a simple box it happens either but because of uniformity of colors its a little hard to see. You can change vertex colors to see this clearly. I think its a bug

Comment: would also suggest if you are using code similar, but not the same as above, post that code. As mentioned I do not see this behaviour.

Comment: @batFinger I've tested this on some other pc and this was solved. Seems the problem is because of driver or something. Anyway Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script does its job.

The problems is caused by old nvidia graphics driver. A new nvidia gameready graphics driver solved the problem.